# How do you see logging from a Meteor Cordova iOS app?

Tags: meteor

From what I understand, doing a `console.log` in a normal Cordova app gets piped to the Xcode debug output, but that doesn't work for my Meteor Cordova iOS app, so I've been doing alerts, which isn't as good.

Comment: [Safari remote debugging](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap#safari-remote-debugging) will show you console.log messages from Xcode's simulator or a connected device.

Comment: Works and has a command line, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ethaan's answer is a good point, but I don't think it is answering the OP's intended question. I am going to re-iterate the comment from @user728291 on the Question since I believe it is the sought answer.

> [Safari Remote Debugging](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap#safari-remote-debugging) will show you console.log messages from
>   Xcode's simulator or a connected device.

And in the case that the hyper-link may someday be moot, I will re-iterate the referenced text from the link:

> If you are doing iOS PhoneGap debugging and have the Safari Develop Menu enabled, you can access the currently active session through the built-in Safari Web Inspector. To activate, go to Develop -> (iPad || iPhone) Simulator (normally, the third menu item) and click the active session you want to connect to. Voila!

Answer (score 1):

> The same way you can use Meteor.isServer and Meteor.isClient booleans
>   to separate your client-side code and server-side code, you can use
>   Meteor.isCordova constant to separate your Cordova/Phonegap-specific
>   code from the rest of code shipped to browsers and mobile devices.

From [Meteor Cordova Phonegap Integration Documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration)

So try with this.

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      console.log('Hi iam on the console from Xcode")
      console.log("Welcome back " + Meteor.user().username);
      console.log("the user with the id  " + Meteor.userId() + " Just logged In");
    }
```

Comment: My `console.log`s are outside of a `if (Meteor.isCordova)` block, so it always runs, including when on Cordova.

Comment: and you have the other consoles inside a Meter call or Metehor method?